# How to place a Spacer between two TextSpan widgets?

Tags: flutter

How to place a Spacer between two TextSpan widgets?

In the next example I have two texts XXX and YYY, and I would like to have a spacer that will push YYY to the right end.

[image]

I want to justify statement XXX and then YYYY right aligned and insert a space between the end of XXX and the beginning of YYY.

I tried the following sample, but it does not work:

```dart
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: [
        TextSpan(text: "xxxxx xxxx xx x xxx xxxxx xxx  xxxx", style: titleStyle),
        const WidgetSpan(child: Spacer()),
        TextSpan(text: "yyyy", style: titleStyle),
      ],
    )
  );
```

Comment: Use a `WidgetSpan` widget and place a `spacer()` within the `widgetspan`?

Comment: @MendelG I did it. But it doesn't work. I have updated OP with a sample code.

Comment: Why this specific issue? why not to use just texts and spacer in a row?

Comment: Simple text in a row will overflow. I want first statement to automatically break lines as provided by TextSpan.

Comment: Actually i am not getting your question you want yyyy to right aligned in that's it?

Comment: @AkshayGupta Yes it is. yyyy right aligned and xxxxx justified and space between the end of xxxxx and the beginning of yyyy. I will update OP.

Comment: Can you let me know your base purpose of doing this?

Comment: Is tis a CSS (presentation) issue or a programing one? What technologies are involved? The spacer has a fixed width?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir This is a Flutter issue. Not CSS.

Comment: @AkshayGupta In truth in my use case YYY is an edit button. I just presented it as another TextSpan to simplify the OP. Nevertheless, I just want  to place it following the XXXX text, but on the right margin.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa could you please show us the ui that you want to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no direct way of doing it, but it can be achieved by using some tricks. One such approach I could think of is using your TextSpan widget with text 'yyyy' twice along with Stack widget, to achieve what you need. The reason for using it twice is that the first YYYY widget will always be invisible but will occupy the same width as the second YYYY and it will always keep a space at the end of the RichText. It's more difficult for me to explain in words, instead the code will be more helpful.
You can also find the following code at [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=81e460d3de81fbe43cd7efaba31c7901)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("Flutter App"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: RichText(
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    text: const TextSpan(
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "xxxxx xxxx xx x xxx xxxxx xxx  xxxx xxxx xxx",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 24,
                            )),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "yyyy",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            fontSize: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: RichText(text: const TextSpan(
            text: "yyyy",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
          ),))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: But at some point it will also overlaps the text isn't it?

Comment: If you give equal width to both the YYYY widget as per your needs, then it should never overlap. You can try to play around with it. It's specially suited for your use case where you want the edit button always right aligned as if it were a part of RichText.

Comment: The idea is that let's say first YYYY widget occupies width of 80, then it will always occupy a space of 80 inside the Rich Text and will always be invisible. Regarding the second YYYY widget, it will always be visible and positioned at the bottom right end of Rich Text.If both 1st and 2nd widget overlaps then 1st widget is already invisible and 2nd widget will be on top of 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably impossible, simply because `RichText` is a [text styling widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/text), not a layout one (as opposed to `Row`, for example). So just try to find another solution for your specific problem using more appropriate widgets and don't waste your time fighting the framework. It's all about common sense.